# Python Recursive Minimax Implementation

Tags: python, recursion, artificial-intelligence

I was examining the AI related projects of Berkeley and I found a recursive implementation of minimax in python.

1)In get action the return value is  return value is

```
self.miniMax(gameState, self.depth)[1]
```

Does this assume that agentIndex is always 0 at the beginning so no need to give an argument for that? And what does [1] stand for?

3)Can I write an iterative version of this code with a helper function? If so how? I am experienced in writing recursive functions with using scheme and I think it will be same(with defining a helper function etc)but I am a little bit confused in Python. Looking at an iterative version of this piece of code would really help me.

Comment: 1) `[1]` means access the first element from the returned result from `self.miniMax()`. `agentIndex` will be `0` if you don't provide it but other than that is says nothing.  2) \ is a continuation character - just means the code continues on the next line. In this example they are unnecessary because list `[ ]` automatically continue. Mathematically expressions often don't. 3) Yes, sure you can write an iterative version, it's harder in my opinion.

Comment: I see now. Since it returns a list it is same as writing myList[1]. But then shouldnt it be 0 since the first element has 0 as an index.

Comment: The `action` is index `1` the cost is `0` - `getAction()` returns the `action`.